# Can somebody explain to me the how these 2 integrations produce different results

Tags: calculus

I am revising for my upcoming maths exam and im pretty much set for it, but when working through a set of example questions these two answers confused me

Question 1:

Evaluate the indefinite intergral:

$$\int 5x^{3} + 3x^{2} dx$$

which becomes:

$$ \frac{5x^{4}}{4} + \frac{3x^{3}}{3} + c $$

$$ \frac{5x^{4}}{4} + x^{3} + c $$

which i understand as, so you could say:

$$ \int ax^{n} + ax^{n} dx \\\\ $$

$$ \frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1}+ \frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1} + c$$

But the question that confused me is:

Integrate to ﬁnd the area under the curve $y = 2x^{3} + 6$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$. I understand how to solve this problem, but want I want to know if why the integration is not the same format as above.

$$ \int (2x^{3} + 6)dx = \frac{x^{4}}{2} + 6x $$

this is now in the format of:

$$ \int ax^{n} + 6 = \frac{x^{n+1}}{a}+ 6x $$ so why is it different to the earlier example? why does the $a$ value become the denominator in the fraction as opposed to it being $x^{n+1}$

Comment: An antiderivative of $2x^3$ is $2x^4\over 4$. This was simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still the same. You just had it mistaken. The denominator is still $n+1$. It just so happened that $n+1 = 4$ and $a=2$ so it simplified to 1/2.

Comment: ah! i see, i was just being stupid then! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int(ax^n+6)dx=\frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1}+6x+C.$$
Hence, the two you wrote is not different from each other.

So,
$$\int(2x^3+6)dx=\frac{2}{3+1}x^{3+1}+6x+C=\frac{2}{4}x^4+6x+C=\frac{1}{2}x^4+6x+C.$$